# CollectionView not displaying 3 columns as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 3 different `UICollectionView`s in the same `UIViewController`. They are working fine. My problem is with the styling, 2 of them need to have the same styling  - meaning 3 columns and some spacing.

This is what i need to achieve:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvOMB.png)

And this is what I got so far: 
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCmx.png)

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == gameCollectionView {
        let width = gameCollectionView.frame.size.width
        return CGSize(width: ((width / 2) - 7), height: 150)
    }
    else {
        let width = paymentCollectionView.bounds.width / 3 // < THIS IS What should give 3 columns 
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 70)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this and preferably explain how it works because I cannot figure it out

UPDATE: As requested - Storyboard for the CollectionView
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4LBl.png)

Comment: can you try with this 'let width = (paymentCollectionView.bounds.width / 3)-10' also show the storyboard collection properties

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I've added the Storyboard screenshot. And tried with your suggestion but it doesnt work. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
let screenWidth = self.CollecionView.frame.width
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth/3)-5, height: (screenWidth/3)-5)
self.CollecionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CGSize(width: ((width - `section's left & right spce` - minimumInteritemSpacing) / `numberofCellYouWant`), height: 150)
```

you can get `minimumInteritemSpacing` from `collectionView.collectionViewLayout` property

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to deploy for **iOS 13 or above** I'd recommend using **Compositional Layout** to achieve this grid.

## Resources

Apple has a great WWDC on this and an SDK that you can download to view their sample code. Here are the links:

[Advances in Collection View Layout WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215/)

[Associated SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/using_collection_view_compositional_layouts_and_diffable_data_sources)

## Recommendation

I'd also recommend wrapping all three collection views inside this single collection view. This can easily be achieved using Compositional Layout.

## Sample Code

The sample below is from the link above. You can layout 3 columns by simply defining it in your group. Alternatively you could layout your items as a fraction of their group container.

```
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                         heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                          heightDimension: .absolute(44))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)
    let spacing = CGFloat(10)
    group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot use Compositional Layout because it's supported from iOS 13+

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this delegate work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == gameCollectionView {
        let width = gameCollectionView.frame.size.width
        return CGSize(width: ((width / 2) - 7), height: 150)
    }
    else {
        let width = (paymentCollectionView.frame.width / 3) - 5 // if you want to more space so increase
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 70)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, got the same result, nothing changed

Comment: let width = (paymentCollectionView.frame.width / 3) - 5 // if you want to more space so increase
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 70)